# Power BI: Creating a bar chart from a "Select All That Apply" question column

Tags: powerbi, survey

I'm analyzing survey data in Power BI and need to visualize a "Select All That Apply" column. This results in a single column with separated responses (see example below).

[image]

I would like to find a way to visualize this so that the data can be reported similar to this format. Ideally I'd like a bar chart, but just as long as I can create something similar to this I will be happy.

[image]

One caveat is that it needs to be linked to the original dataset so that the user can apply filters. I tried creating a new table that countrows() and filters() the original dataset but then they are no longer connected.

Comment: What do you mean by not longer connected? Did you created a calculated table? If so, it does work with filtering from slicer interaction. Assuming it is text, you may want to create a DAX **measure** with the use of [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/find-function-dax) (e.g. whether “a” is part of) to filter and count rows accordingly.  Then you can use that measure in another visual (table, bar chart, etc .. )

Comment: Hey, I did not create a calculated table. I manually entered a new table then used a DAX calculated column. I think using a measure is genius, that might solve it

Comment: I see. Yes, calculated columns will not be “refreshed” when applying any filters (same with the calculated tables). Need to define a measure which should be similar to your calculated column definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question.

I was using a Calculated Column. I was able to instead use a Measure. Using a Measure meant the table was now dynamic and would respond to any slicer on the original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query Split that column into multiple rows.  Right-click on the column header, choose Split Column By Delimiter, and:

[image]

Comment: If I split it, how can I gather the counts to create a bar chart?